# Question about Normal Coordinates on a Kaehler Manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I am currently reading FY Zheng's textbook, "Complex Differential Geometry". In section 7.4 Proposition 7.14, he is trying to prove thata metric $h$ Kaehler is equivalent to the statement, "For any $p \in M$, there exists a local holomorphic coordinate $(z_1,...,z_n)$ in a neighborhood of $p$ such that $h_{i \bar j}(p)=\delta_{ij}, dh_{i\bar j}(p)=0$. Such a coordinate is said to be normal at $p$."

In the proof, he says "By a constant linear change of coordinate if necessary, we may assume that $h_{i\bar j}(p)=\delta_{ij}, 1\leq i,j\leq n$." What exactly does he mean by "constant linear change", because to me the words "constant" and "linear" together seem contradicting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'd like to choose a coordinate system for which the metric at $ p$ is identity. We can do it as follows: let  $ \phi_i $ be coordinate system and $ g_{ij} $ be the metric in these coordinates. Let $ C $ be the matrix such that $ C^T g_{ij}(p) C = \delta_{ij} $. Define new coordinates $ \phi' $ as $ \phi_i' = C_{ij} \phi_j $. (This is a constant linear change in coordinates). Then in the $ \phi' $ coordinates, the metric at $p$ is $ g'_{ij}(p) = \delta_{ij} $.

Comment: Thank you @user226970! After I obtain the $\phi'_i$, how would I use these coordinates to obtain the matrix for the metric $g'_{ij}$ (that is, the matrix $g'_{ij}$ before I evaluate at $p$)?

Comment: In addition, @user226970 , if for instance we have a $2$-dim manifold w/ coordinates $(z_1, z_2)$, and we want to have $(z'_1, z'_2)$, we would do (as you wrote): $z'_1=C_{1j}z_j$.. but if $j=1,2$, we have $z'_1=C_{11}z_1$ and $z'_1=C_{12}z_2$. In this case, which would be $z'_1$?

Comment: Hi Alvey. It is not true $ z_1 ' = C_{11} z_1 $, rather it is $ z_1' = C_{11} z_1 + C_{12} z_2 $. In addition

Comment: the new metric at a different point will have the same formula. Maybe you refresh on how the metric transforms under coordinate change and see if you can show these things I'm saying explicitly.

Comment: Oh yes I always forget Einstein summation notation. Thank you!